# Online UPS hack

Tags: transformer, dc

I have an ONLINE UPS rated for 10Kva, by design it transforms input AC->DC->AC output, the last part of transformation (DC->AC) comes with a loss around 8% of power from what I've read so far.

Considering that I have most of my house lighting working in DC (with a transformer from AC->DC) I'm thinking to cut the double transformation (DC->AC and then AC->DC to consumer) by taking the power directly from ups battery terminals which is DC 240V.

The question is: what's your opinion about this setup ? Power save by cutting dual transformation will really save some watts-hours or it really doesn't worth the effort ? Tried to find a DC-DC transformer but they're not so common ...

Comment: The UPS is designed to prevent over-discharge of the batteries by shutting down the DC-to-AC inverter section. If you connect directly to the batteries, you'll have no such protection.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but could be solved easily with a in-line contactor controlled by AC output of the ups, NO AC OUTPUT on ups terminals = contactor disconnects and cuts the drain from batteries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

92% efficiency is actually pretty good.

The reason mains voltage isn't at harmless, let's say, 5V is that the higher the voltage of your system, the lower the current you have to transport to bring the same amount of power, and the lower the current, the thinner the wires and the lesser the voltage drop across a wire.

This means that if you're planning to distribute low-voltage DC, you'd have to make sure the cabling is meant to support the much higher current you'll draw, and also, every meter of cable, every plug and contact, drop another part of your sparse amount of voltage.

I wouldn't be surprised if the energy savings by not doing DC->AC->DC conversion get eaten up by the higher losses. Also, think about ecological and economic costs:

1. you'll have to lie a second pair of wiring, and that must be thicker than your 240V cabling. Copper is expensive, because you need a lot of electrical power to purify it to a degree that allows usage as cable.
2. Your devices don't directly run off the same DC voltage, anyway. Most digital devices have power supplies that offer them exactly the voltage they need – or dozens of different voltage rails, for more complex devices like PCs, Laptops, TVs etc.

> Tried to find a DC-DC transformer but they're not so common ...

*smile* that's because there physically is no such thing as a DC transformer. When you convert DC to DC of a different voltage, you hack it (essentially making an alternating current out of it), and typically charge the magnetic field within a coil or transformer core with it, then use that stored magnetic energy to produce the output DC voltage using clever control mechanisms.